# Getting error of undefined is not json with put request axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm getting an error of `undefined is not Json` after sending an object of `formData` with `put` request.

The construction of updatedData :

```
const urlToObject = async (url) => {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let blob = await response.blob();
  return new File([blob], data?.photo, { type: blob.type });
        };
const picture = await urlToObject(STABLES.UPLOAD_FOLDER_BASE_URL + data?.photo);
updatedData.append("mainPhoto", picture);
const emptyDocument = JSON.stringify({
      title: "",
      caption: "",
      slug: "",
      body: "",
      tags: [],
      categories: [],
});
updatedData.append("document", emptyDocument);
```

My request function is :

```
const updatePost = async  ({ updatedData, slug, token }) => {
      try {
        const config = {
          headers: {
           "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          }
        };
    
        const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/posts/${slug}`, updatedData, config);
        return data;
      } catch (e) {
        if(e.response && e.response.data.message) {
          throw new Error(e.response.data.message);
        }
        throw new Error(e.message);
      }
    };
```

I verified that `updatedData` is not empty and it contains the data i need but when i `console.log(req.body)` in the BackEnd `req.body={}` is empty and i get the error.

I've tried :

- To change the `Content-type` with `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`
- To change the `Content-type` with `"Content-Type": "application/json"` i get `req.body.document` but an empty `req.body.mainPhoto` it doesn`t have the file for the image.
- Added this line in server.js but couldn't fix or understand why i'm getting an empty body:

`app.use(express.json());`

`app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

`app.use(express.json({ limit: '10mb' }));`

`app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }));`

Comment: Can you give use the code when you construct `updatedData`? When using form-data it should be FormData object

Comment: That seems strange. Have you tested it with Postman to ensure that the API can handle the form-data request

Comment: Yes it works with Postman but i can't find the bug in my code